# How to solve this initial value problem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

How do I solve this initial value problem?

$y'=2x-2\sqrt{\max(y,0)}$

$y(0)=0$

I've never seen a problem of this type with the "max" and I don't know how to begin.

It must have a unique solution $y:[0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$

I know the solution must be of the type $y(x)=cx^2$.

Comment: Picard's existence/uniqueness theorem doesn't apply here, because the right hand side is not Lipschitz continuous in $y$. In fact Picard iteration doesn't even work at all, it gives an oscillatory sequence. I suspect this equation may actually have no solution, which is surprising, because I thought there was an existence theorem for $x'=f(x,y)$ whenever $f$ is just continuous.

Comment: Assume $y\ge 0$, solve under this assumption and then check if the assumption holds.

Comment: @mlu If I assume $y \geq 0$, let $y=z^2$, and thereby convert the equation to $z z' = x-z$, Wolfram gives a solution...but it isn't defined at $x=0$. How are you supposed to deal with that? (The corresponding equation $z dz + (z-x) dx = 0$ is not exact, so proceeding would require you to somehow find an integrating factor.)

Comment: You can substitute $z=x/\sqrt{y}$, that will give you a separable equation. Check any solutions making $z'=0$ separately. This will actually give you a solution of the form you have already proposed. In the form you have in the comment, try $u=x/z$ and make sure to test special solutions that would make both sides identically 0. Humans are smarter than Wolfram.

Comment: I have proved that $y$ must be positive, which implies that your equation is $y' = 2x - 2\sqrt y$. Unfortunately, I have no idea whether this equation has a unique solution, because (as @Ian noted) the derivative with respect to $y$ of the right-hand side goes to infinity when $y \to 0$, which means that the l.h.s. is not uniformly continuous and thus the Picard-Lindelöf theorem does not apply. Are you sure that the problem does not ask you to merely find a solution of the type $c x^2$ (much easier)? Otherwise, this looks like a very difficult problem. In what context did you encounter it?

Comment: I have taken a look at your past questions and none attains the level of difficulty of this one. Are you sure that you are giving us the correct statement of the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Assume first that $y(x) \le 0 \ \forall x \in [0, \infty)$. The your equation will look like $y' = 2x$, so that $y = x^2 + c$; since $y(0) = 0$, then $c=0$, so $y=x^2$, but this one is not negative, so we have reached a contradiction. Therefore, there must exist $x_0 >0$ with $y(x_0) > 0$.

Let $(a,b) \subset [0, \infty)$ be the *maximal* (with respect to inclusion) interval containing $x_0$ on which $y > 0$, with $b$ possibily $\infty$. Maximality and the continuity of $y$ imply that $y(a) = y(b) = 0$.

Assume that $b$ is finite. If $y(b) = 0$, then $y'(b) = 2b > 0$. By the continuity of $y'$, there must exist some interval $(b - \varepsilon, b + \varepsilon)$ on which $y' > 0$, which means that on this interval $y$ must *strictly* increase. But $b - \varepsilon \in (a,b)$ on which $y$ was already *strictly* positive, so $0 < y(b - \varepsilon) < y(b) = 0$, which is a contradiction, therefore $b = \infty$.

So far, we have discovered that $y > 0$ on $(a, \infty)$, with $y(a) = 0$, and that there exist $\varepsilon > 0$ such that and $y(x) < 0$ on $(a - \varepsilon, a) \subset [0,a)$; consider *the largest* $\varepsilon \in (0, a)$ with this property. Think of what happens in $a - \varepsilon$: the maximality in the choice of $\varepsilon$ implies that $y(a - \varepsilon) = 0$, so $y' (a - \varepsilon) = 2 (a - \varepsilon) > 0$, so there must exist a small $r>0$ such that $y' > 0$ on the interval $(a - \varepsilon - r, a - \varepsilon + r)$, which means that $y$ is *strictly* increasing on it. But this means that $0 = y(a - \varepsilon) < y(a - \varepsilon + r) < 0$, which is a contradiction.

We have two possibilities: either $\varepsilon = a$, so that $y < 0$ on $(0, a)$; or $a = 0$ and there is no $\varepsilon$ as assumed. To rule out the first possibility, use the same argument as in the first paragraph: you will get $y(x) = x^2$, which is not negative as it should on $(0,a)$, so this case is not possible.

Therefore, we have proved that $y(x) > 0$ on $(0, \infty)$, with $y(0) = 0$. Thus, your equation becomes $y' = 2x - \sqrt y$. Solving this equation is far from easy, though. The change of unknown $y = u^2$ turns it into $uu' = x - u$, which is sorter but not simpler.

In any case, in order to show that a solution exists you don't need any of the above: just assume it to be of the form $y = c x^2$ and, after plugging this into the equation you will get that $c$ must verify $c + \sqrt c - 1 = 0$, which has a single positive solution: $c = \dfrac {3-\sqrt 5} 2$. Showing that this solution is unique, though, seems very difficult, and I do not even know whether this is true (everything boils down to the fact that one cannot use the Picard-Lindelöf theorem because the left-hand side is not uniformly continuous, its derivative with respect to $y$ being infinite in $y=0$).

Comment: Nice analysis. Now we can use the trajectory $y_0=cx^2$ as reference and prove that if we start in (x,y), x>0 and $y<y_0$ then as x decreases the slope will be larger than for the $y_0$ curve and the distance to this tracectory will increase so we must hit the x axis, with slope 2x. If we start above the $y_0$ trajectory the slope will be less and the positive distance will increase as x goes to 0 an the curve will hit the y axis, with slope -1.